# Limit checked checkbox in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form with a set of checkboxes, how to make the user can only check a fixed number of them

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Are you interested in limiting the total count, or limiting them to a certain group? Like they can check two of three, or is there some other type of restriction?

Comment: I want to limit the total count..the html is just a form with some checkboxes and a submit button

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This example will count the number of checked inputs after each one is checked and compare against the maximum number allowed. If the maximum is exceeded, the remaining checkboxes are disabled.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var max = 3;
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.change(function(){
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
    });
});
```

Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/Ghtbu/1/

Comment: it works nice :)..just wondering: when I replace "jQuery" with "$" why it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you have any other libraries loaded that use the `$` object such as prototype? `jQuery` should be synonymous with `$` and short-hand for `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 5):

This binds to each checkbox a bit of logic that checks to see how many checkboxes are checked in the current form. If that number equals 2, we disable all other boxes.

```
$("form").on("click", ":checkbox", function(event){
  $(":checkbox:not(:checked)", this.form).prop("disabled", function(){
    return $(this.form).find(":checkbox:checked").length == 2;
  });
});
```

This works on a per-form basis, meaning you can have multiple forms that don't touch the inputs of one another. In the demo below I showcase three forms, all of which contain three checkboxes. The restriction of 2 checkboxes is limited to their respective forms.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/epanex/4/edit