# How to give limitation to dynamic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I face a checkbox problem, dynamic name of a checkbox buy[]. I want to give a limitation. User can select only 5 or 6 checkboxes. Checkboxes come from database table row base. Clear and simple question. I already coding it but need little help if choice checkbox `name='bye'`, then my script works, but `forEach` does not work. Give me solution for dynamic checkboxes with limited selection.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    /***********************************************
    * Limit number of checked checkboxes script- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
    * This notice must stay intact for usage
    * Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and  100s more
    ***********************************************/

    function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
        var checkgroup=checkgroup
        var limit=limit
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
            checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
            var checkedcount=0
            for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
                checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
            if (checkedcount>limit){
                alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" courses")
                this.checked=false
                }

            if (checkedcount>limit){
                alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" courses")
                this.checked=false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .table tr th {border:1px solid #008080}

    </style>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action='registration_courses_add.php' autocomplete="off" method='post'  id="world" name="world" >
                                <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" id="ctl00_MainContainer_btnLoad" class="button-margin SearchKey">

    <h3>Please select course for registration : </h3>
    <p style="color:green">Note: You can select maximum 6 courses </p>

    <table align="center" tabindex="6" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_MainContainer_gvRegisteredCourse" style="width: 98%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-left: 17px;">

                <tr style="  color: White;
      background-color: SeaGreen;
      height: 25px;">
                    <th>Course id</th>
                    <th>Course title</th>
                    <th>Course credits</th>
                    <th>Course status</th>
                    <th>Selection</th>


                </tr>

            <?php 
            $db=require "script_database/connect.php"; 

            $query = "
    select 
    c.course_id,c.id,
    c.course_title,
    c.course_credits,
    c.course_status 
    from course c 
    where 
    c.course_id NOT IN (select course_id from completed_course where student_id='1229CSE00241')
    group by c.id 
    ";




            $run=mysql_query($query);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
            $post_id=$row['course_id'];
            $post_date=$row['course_title'];
            $post_author=$row['course_credits'];
            $post_title=$row['course_status'];



            ?>


                <tr align="center" >
                    <td><?php echo $post_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $post_date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $post_author; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $post_title; ?></td>
                    <td><?php print "<input type='checkbox' name='buy[]' value='{$row['id']}' /> "?></td>
                    //if i change buy[] to bye then check box limit work but  foreach{} not work for check box 
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>



                </table>





            </form> 

            <script type="text/javascript">

    //Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
    checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.buy, 6)
    //here is the problem
    </script>



    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please clarify little properly.

Comment: Remember `mysql_*` gives hackers lots of loopholes to hack your site. Its sin to  use `mysql_*`.

Comment: i query from database table and find some of courses but student can only select 5-6 courses. so how can i give a course limitation by use check box.

Comment: You already gave limitation using Javascript to limit to 6 `checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.buy, 6)` , So what is the issue ?

Comment: my check box name is bye[]. i use foreach condition and store data in database. if i  add bye then check box select work but database don't store data give me a problem messege:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\crf\registration_courses_add.php on line 16

Comment: buy or bye , you decide.

Comment: So, they can't select 4, and they can't select 7?

Comment: how can i give a limitation in check box
<input type='checkbox' name='buy[]' value='{$row['id']}' /> "?>
buy[] that mean if i use foreach{} loop i can store check box selected data but how can i fixed check box . example user can select only 6 checkbox

Comment: @Al-mahbubKhan , yes you are correct

Comment: why correct?? please anyone solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure javascript method. This is will allow you to use the function for more than one form/group of checkboxes

Here I have added a classname to the elements for my selector, i have commented out another way if you don't want to use a class name

**With Class Name:**

```
var boxes=document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');
```

**Without Class Name:**

```
var boxes=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
```

I have used a custom data attribute to set the maximum amount of checkboxes for the group of elements. This will allow the function to run with different limits depending on the set data-max attribute and name.

```js
function limit(){
  var count=0;
  //Get all elements with the class name of Boxes
  var boxes=document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');
// ---- Or ------  
//Get all input elements with the type of checkbox.
//var boxes=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  //(this) is used to target the element triggering the function.
   for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
    //If checkbox is checked AND checkbox name is = to (this) checkbox name +1 to count
    if(boxes[i].checked&&boxes[i].name==this.name){count++;}
  }
  //If count is more then data-max="" of that element, uncheck last selected element
  if(count>this.getAttribute("data-max")){
    this.checked=false;
    alert("Maximum of "+this.getAttribute("data-max")+".");
  }
}
//----Stack Overflow Snippet use---\\
window.onload=function(){
var boxes=document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');
// Use if you don't want to add a class name to the elements
//var boxes=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
    boxes[i].addEventListener('change',limit,false);
  }
}
```

```html
<b>Name:</b> bye[] <b>Limit:</b> 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="5" name="bye[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="5" name="bye[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="5" name="bye[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="5" name="bye[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="5" name="bye[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="5" name="bye[]"/>
<hr/>
  <b>Name:</b> hello[] <b>Limit:</b> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="2" name="hello[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="2" name="hello[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" data-max="2" name="hello[]"/>
```

If you don't want to use `window.onload` to set your eventlisteners you can simply add the onchange attribute to your checkbox elements `onChange="limit(this)"` and change `function limit(e){` and replace all `this` to `e`

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible!

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

[Limit checked checkbox in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458924/limit-checked-checkbox-in-a-form)
http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/Ghtbu/1/
those are helpful

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="function.js"></script>
```

//function.js

```
jQuery(function(){
    var max = 4;
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.change(function(){
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
    });
});
```

done... :)

Comment: yes i know ... But i use it only for this course registration form so student can select only a limitation of course selection. As system analyst i know if i don't give ant limit ,they creating some problem to select many subject.