# Limit checked amount of grouped checkboxes (i.e. max 2 groups)

Tags: javascript

This might be simple to solve, but I ran into many issues, so I hope someone can help.
I have groups of checkboxes (options coming form a db), something like this

- area1: 4 options
- area2: 6 options
- areaX: X options etc.

The user has to select at least one option from one group/area, but no more than 2/group from max. 2 groups/areas (aka max. 4 options; max 2 options per group/area; max 2 groups/areas).

I know how to limit the amount of checked boxes checked for a simple scenario, but I'm blank with the above problem (also found some posts, i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441866/how-to-give-limitation-to-dynamic-checkboxes/30442693#30442693).

I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

So far I have this (limit the checkboxes per group)

```js
$(function(){
  var max = 2;
  var checkboxes = $('.area > input[type="checkbox"]');
  console.log(checkboxes);
  checkboxes.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var set = checkboxes.filter('[name="'+ this.name +'"]');
    var current = set.filter(':checked').length;
    return current <= max;

  });
});
```

```css
.c {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c">

        <div id="area1" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1-1" id="option1" name="option1" /><label for="option1">Option 11</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1-2" id="option2" name="option1" /><label for="option2">Option 12</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1-3" id="option3" name="option1" /><label for="option3">Option 13</label><br />
        </div>

        <div id="area2" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2-1" id="option21" name="option2" /><label for="option21">Option 21</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2-2" id="option22" name="option2" /><label for="option22">Option 22</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2-3" id="option23" name="option2" /><label for="option23">Option 23</label><br />
        </div>

        <div id="area3" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3-1" id="option31" name="option3" /><label for="option31">Option 31</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3-2" id="option32" name="option3" /><label for="option32">Option 32</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3-3" id="option33" name="option3" /><label for="option33">Option 33</label><br />
        </div>

        <div id="area4" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4-1" id="option41" name="option4" /><label for="option41">Option 41</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4-2" id="option42" name="option4" /><label for="option42">Option 42</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4-3" id="option43" name="option4" /><label for="option43">Option 43</label><br />
        </div>

    </div>
```

/ K

Comment: Have you tried anything for this? A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: i think you can listen to the check event and when the condition you want happens you can disable all the unselected checkboxs

Comment: I did, but nothing to solve the above problem.
This is so far what I got: limit the amount of checked checkboxes per group. I need to limit to max. 2 groups.

Vanilla JS can also go. Dosen't have to be jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/kapris/t3m7dg04/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since vanilla is also a go you can try the following

```js
(function () {

      var checkboxes = [];
      var areas = [];
      var maxInArea = null;
      var maxOverall = null;

      function init() {
        //initialize checkboxes and areas as well as limits
        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        areas = document.getElementsByClassName('area');
        maxInArea = 2;
        maxOverall = 4;

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', handleCheckboxClick, false); //add an event listener to each checkbox
      }


      function handleCheckboxClick(e) {
        var currentArea;
        var currentAreaCheckboxes;

        currentArea = e.target.parentElement; //get the current area...
        currentAreaCheckboxes = currentArea.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'); //...to count its checked checkboxes

        if ((_getActiveCheckboxesInArea(currentAreaCheckboxes) > maxInArea) //check limits per area...
          || (_getActiveCheckboxesOverall() > maxOverall) ){ //...then overall
          e.target.checked = false;
        }
      }

      function _getActiveCheckboxesInArea(areaCheckboxes) {
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < areaCheckboxes.length; i++)
          if (areaCheckboxes[i].checked) count++;

        return count;
      }

      function _getActiveCheckboxesOverall() {
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
          if (checkboxes[i].checked) count++;

        return count;
      }

      init();

    })();
```

As you can see the trick is to have a count for the current area detecting the area parent element when the checkbox is clicked. It looks quite like a long script, but since it is Vanilla you have more control, simplicity and performance than using jQuery, you will notice as soon you give it the first read

Comment: Thanks for this. Your solution works as well very fine.
I also voted your solution up, but it seems that I still have to earn 2 points before I do that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by keeping an array of all names for checked boxes, and comparing it against the most recently clicked box:

```js
const max = 2
    let totals = []

  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.area > input[type="checkbox"]')
    checkboxes.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            
            //check within group
            let within = totals.filter(name => name === e.target.name)
            if(e.target.checked && within.length >= max && totals.indexOf(e.target.name) > -1){
                console.log("max within group reached")
                e.preventDefault()
                return
            }
            
            //check all groups
            let without = totals.filter((name, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(name) === idx)
            if(e.target.checked && without.length >= max && without.indexOf(e.target.name) === -1){
                console.log("max groups reached")
                e.preventDefault()
                return
            }
        
            if(e.target.checked){
                totals.push(e.target.name)
            }else{
                totals.splice(totals.indexOf(e.target.name),1)
            }
        })
    })
```

```css
.c {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c">

        <div id="area1" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1-1" id="option1" name="option1" /><label for="option1">Option 11</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1-2" id="option2" name="option1" /><label for="option2">Option 12</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1-3" id="option3" name="option1" /><label for="option3">Option 13</label><br />
        </div>

        <div id="area2" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2-1" id="option21" name="option2" /><label for="option21">Option 21</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2-2" id="option22" name="option2" /><label for="option22">Option 22</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2-3" id="option23" name="option2" /><label for="option23">Option 23</label><br />
        </div>

        <div id="area3" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3-1" id="option31" name="option3" /><label for="option31">Option 31</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3-2" id="option32" name="option3" /><label for="option32">Option 32</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3-3" id="option33" name="option3" /><label for="option33">Option 33</label><br />
        </div>

        <div id="area4" class="area">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4-1" id="option41" name="option4" /><label for="option41">Option 41</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4-2" id="option42" name="option4" /><label for="option42">Option 42</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4-3" id="option43" name="option4" /><label for="option43">Option 43</label><br />
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works like a charm.
I voted your solution up, but it seems that I still have to earn 2 points before I do that.
Thanks.